# Angular directive which fires a jquery ui widget when finished rendering

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create an angular directive which fires a jquery ui widget when the template has finished rendering. The template is in a separate html file, the data for this template is put on the rootscope asynchronously in a different component.

The problem is that the call to the jquery ui widget (jquery ui tabs in this case) happens too soon, the template hasn't finished rendering yet. The tabs don't render properly. When I put the call to the tabs widget inside a $timeout with a delay of half a second it works fine, but that doesn't appear like a solid solution to me.

Here's the code:

```
house.directive('floorDirective', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/floor.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.$watch('navigationDto', function(navigationDto) {
                scope.toolNodes = [];
                if (navigationDto != undefined) {
                    var treeNodes = navigationDto.TreeNodes;
                    for (var x = 0; x < treeNodes.length; x++) {
                        if (treeNodes[x].Id == -100) { //File
                            scope.menuNodes = treeNodes[x].Children;
                        }
                        else {
                            scope.toolNodes.push(treeNodes[x]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                element.children(':first').tabs({
                    active: 1
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And here's the (simplified) template:

```
<div id="floor">
    <ul class="floor-tabs">
        <li data-ng-repeat="treeNode in navigationDto.TreeNodes" id="{{treeNode.Id}}">
            <a href="#tab{{treeNode.Id}}">{{treeNode.Name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="floor-menu">
        <div data-ng-repeat="itemNode in menuNodes" id="tab{{itemNode.Id}}">
            <a href="#">itemNode.Name</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="floor-tool" data-ng-repeat="toolNode in toolNodes" id="tab{{toolNode.Id}}">
        <div data-ng-repeat="categoryNode in toolNode.Children">
            <h2>{{categoryNode.Name}}</h2>
            <div data-ng-repeat="itemNode in categoryNode.Children">
        <a href="#">itemNode.Name</a>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to fire the jquery widget at exact the right time when the template has finished rendering? Or am I looking at the problem the wrong way?

Comment: If this is being rendered in the ngView, you could listen for the `$viewContentLoaded` event before firing your jQuery UI widget.  http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngView